# Why User model inheritance doesn't work properly?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I'm trying to use a **User** model inheritance in my django application. Model looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager

class MyUser(User):
    ICQ = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    objects = UserManager()
```

and authentication backend looks like this:

```
import sys

from django.db import models
from django.db.models import get_model
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

class AuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, email=None, username=None, password=None):
        try:            
            if email:
                user = self.user_class.objects.get(email = email)
            else:
                user = self.user_class.objects.get(username = username)

            if user.check_password(password):
                return user

        except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return self.user_class.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except self.user_class.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    @property
    def user_class(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_user_class'):
            self._user_class = get_model(*settings.CUSTOM_USER_MODEL.split('.', 2))
            if not self._user_class:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured('Could not get custom user model')
        return self._user_class
```

But if I'm trying to authenticate - there is an "*MyUser matching query does not exist*" error on the **self.user_class.objects.get(username = username)** call. It looks like admin user created on base syncing (I'm using sqlite3) stores into **User** model instead of **MyUser** (username and password are right). Or it's something different?

What I'm doing wrong? This is an example from http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to what the blog post you linked to says, storing this kind of data in a profile model is still the recommended way in Django. Subclassing `User` has all kinds of problems, one of which is the one you are hitting: Django has no idea you have subclassed `User` and happily creates and reads `User` models within the Django code base. The same is true for any other 3rd party app you might like to use.

Have a look at [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3011) on Django's issue tracker to get some understanding of the underlying problems of subclassing `User`

Comment: Ok, thank you, I've tried that because of fact that this kind of User model extention was describes in a russian translation of DjangoBook as a good way. Unfortunately, as I see, it's not.